# Can the number of order-sequences of a group of order $n$ be determined efficiently?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

Let $n\ge 1$ and $G$ a group of order $n$. Determine the order of every element of $G$ and list the orders increasing.

> Can the number of possible order-sequences be determined efficiently ?

For example, a group of order $6$ has the possible order-sequences

$$1,2,2,2,3,3$$ and $$1,2,3,3,6,6$$

so there are two possible order-sequences for $n=6$.

The number of order-sequences gives a lower bound for the number of groups of order $n$.

> Additional question : Can the number of groups with a given order-sequence be determined efficiently ?

Comment: I would guess that the most sensible way to do this would be to compute the conjugacy classes of $G$, and there are good algorithms for doing that.