Bound on the no. of order sequences of a group
Can we have a bound on the no. of order sequences of a group $G$ of order $n$ ?
The order sequence of a finite group G is the list of orders of elements of the group, arranged in non-decreasing order. Example, order-sequence($\mathbb{Z}_{6}$) = ($1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6$) and order-sequence($S_{3}$) = ($1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3$).

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151491/number-of-isomorphism-types-of-finite-groups

In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631047/can-the-number-of-order-sequences-of-a-group-of-order-n-be-determined-efficien, @Derek Holt mentioned that "I would guess that the most sensible way to do this would be to compute the conjugacy classes of G". Could you please elaborate it ?
